# Contract Ensures unproven for GUID

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I m having a ensures unproven: `!ReferenceEquals(Contract.Result<T>(), null)`
that contract is on an interface I have no control of

my implementation is something like this

```
    public Guid Blah()
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        if(ReferenceEquals(guid, null))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This shoul");
        }

        return guid;
    }
```

I tired with contract assumes instead of the if and some variations of the code above, but still getting the warning, any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be complete. A Guid is a valuetype and can't be null anyway.

Comment: I know, this is why the ensures unrpoven is a bit of a mistery to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is an interaction with the generic types. If you fix the type to `Guid` it works fine... I think this is a bug in Code Contracts, so I've filed [a question on the Code Contracts forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-nz/codecontracts/thread/5bd9eecc-86a6-4997-b7b9-d9908cdad53e).